# how to create a factory in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, class, zend-framework2, factory-pattern, servicemanager

in my `Module.php` i have the fallowing methods that i would like to move them in a `factory class` so that i wont clutter the `Module class`:

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'account-index' => function ($controllerManager) {
                $serviceManager = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();
                $accountService = $serviceManager->get('account-service');

                return new Controller\IndexController($accountService);
            }
        )
    );
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'account-service' => function ($serviceManages) {
                return new Service\Account;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

right now i have:

and where shall i put this `factory class`, maybe in a `Factory` folder?

any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually put my factories into `../module/yourmodule/src/yourmodule/Factory`.

in your `../module/yourmodule/config/module.config.php` you then have to configure your service_manager like so:

```
'service_manager' => array(
   'factories' => array(
      'yourfactory' => 'yourmodule\Factory\yourfactory',
   ),
),
```

in `yourfactory.php` You then have to implent the FactoryInterface and set the service locator. Once you done this you should be able to call the service the usual way for controllers, forms etc.

```
namespace Application\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class yourfactory implements FactoryInterface
{

private $config;

private $serviceLocator;

public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    return $servicelocator->get('Your\Service');
}
```

After that you can just define functions in your `yourfactory.php`. In your Controller you call functions like so `$serviceManager->get('yourfactory')->yourfunction(yourarguments);`

Comment: Almost. A Factory should only return the specific Service-Class. You shouldn't use a Factory like it would be a Service or a Model. i.e: `createService() { $db = $sl->get('db'); return= new Gateway($db); }`